# Spring @RequestBody inheritance

Tags: java, json, spring, inheritance, jackson

I've read several posts where this was tried to be explained, but I couldn't get it working. I have a scenario where the input `JSON` to my service can be of several subtypes. Basically, I have a base class `UserDto` and then `ClientDto` and `OwnerDto` both of which extend from `UserDto.` I'd like to achieve that the controller is able to resolve concrete subtype of `UserDto` into object of the correct class. So something like this.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void doSomething(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
        ClientDto client = (ClientDto) user;
        // do something
    }
```

I tried something like this. Basically I want to determine the type of the concrete object by the field `profileType` which is of type enum `ProfileType` with values `OWNER` and `CLIENT`.

**UserDto.java**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "profileType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClientDto.class, name = "Client"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OwnerDto.class, name = "Owner")
})
public class UserDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 0, max = 256)
    private ProfileType profileType;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 0, max = 512)
    private String email;

    // ...
}
```

**ClientDto.java**

```
public class ClientDto extends UserDto {

    private Integer salary;

    private Integer efficiency;

    // ... 
}
```

I tried posting the following JSON to this end-point.

```
{
        "email": "eddie.barra22@gmail.com",
        "profileType": "CLIENT",
        "salary": "100",
        "efficiency": "99"
    }
```

And I expected this to be resolved to a type of `ClientDto`. Instead, I only got a **400 Bad Request** error.

The questions are:

1. How do I fix this, and have the `@RequestBody` inheritance working?
2. Is there a way to specify annotations on the subtypes rather than defining all of them on the supertype?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your code.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "profileType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClientDto.class, name = "CLIENT"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OwnerDto.class, name = "OWNER")
})
public class UserDTO {
 .....
}
```

1. You said ProfileType enum has **OWNER** and **CLIENT**. But you have specified in `JsonSubTypes.Type` as Client and Owner. hence doesn't match
2. change `JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS` to `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is it possible to annotate such behaviour on a subclass level?

Comment: Well yeah, but for any new subtype you then need to remember to update the parent