# Spring controller overloading request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I'm currently building a rest controller with spring boot for user management.

I have a update user endpoint which receives a json file with the updated user data.

Now the problem is that there are different types of users which inherit from a base user... students and supervisors.

If I want to update a student, the json file has a "degree" values which a supervisor doesn't have.

So the following approach doesn't work because degree is not mapped to anything.

```
@PutMapping(value = "/users/current")
public void updateUser(@RequestBody User user)
```

Is there an approach to solve this without using two different routes for students and supervisors? It would need some kind of overloading...

Comment: just add the field to `User` (or create a class containing all fields) and let the degree field optional?

Comment: It's not just degree so adding it to user would blow up user too much. Creating a class containing all values would work. But is that good style? That would be redundant code to the user/student/supervisor classes.

Comment: You could do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48733012/10871900 or https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance